# Can you use (any) Spring's functionality outside of Spring (Boot)?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have just built a RESTful web service with Spring Boot.

I now want to utilise the RESTful web service and start making calls to it by building a java console application (eventually adding GUI and security).

I was wondering if I can use any of the Spring functionality outside of the Spring (Boot) environment and use it in my java console application? For example, can I use Spring's RestTemplate in my non-Spring java application to make the REST api calls? I am new to Spring and I want to stick as close to Spring as possible. I think you can't, but I just want to make sure.

If not possible, I know you can create non-web application with Spring. Is it possible to integrate a GUI? Might not be best practice, just exploring what is possible and conventional.

Comment: Yes, you can new the class instance and then use it, RestTemplate just make http client easier.

Comment: Try to add needed dependencies of Spring instead of Spring Boot. To make REST api calls you can use `curl` from bash, google hoe to do it from Java code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Boot is not coupled, in any way, to an application type. You can run command-line only apps, batch apps, web apps or any other kind of apps with it. You can even benefit from Spring Boot's auto-configuration.

In the case of the `RestTemplate` you may want to import `spring-web` directly rather than `spring-boot-starter-web`. Or you could add the starter and exclude the embedded container (`spring-boot-starter-tomcat`). Spring Boot will auto-adapt and not start an embedded web server in that case.

Comment: Hi Stephane. Nice answer! But I have added implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-web' on my Non-Spring Boot java project and it is not finding the dependency. Kindly check my gradle.file and help

`
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8 // java 8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  // JSON handling annotations
  implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-web'

  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}

`